# Ubuntu 14.04.3 - Qualcomm Atheros WLAN - not working - Lenovo Z51-70

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, atheros

I'm new to ubuntu. I have installed Ubuntu 14.04.03 LTS in my Lenovo Z51-70 laptop with Windows 10 dual boot. But the Ubuntu 14.04.3 - Qualcomm Atheros WLAN is not working. not able to connect to WiFi. Help Me.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` terminal command.

Comment: try to install `wpa_supplicant` and try to `modprobe athk5` or a similar athk driver.

Comment: find your chipset using `lshw|less` or duckduckgo.com and search the correct driver there: https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/Drivers . Then try to load the correct module.

Comment: @Pilot6  lspci -knn | grep Net -A2
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Atheros Device [168c:0041] (rev 20)
 Subsystem: Lenovo Device [17aa:3545]
04:00.0 Display controller [0380]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Venus XTX [Radeon HD 8890M / R9 M275X] [1002:6820] (rev ff)
this is the output for what u asked

Comment: Please [edit] your question, if you want to add information. Especially file or program output [listings](/editing-help#code) (with the help of the `{}` button in the editor toolbar) are much more readable there and overall it's best to have everything relevant in one place. Also, comments may be deleted for various reasons.